# How to set a date picker for QR Code to select in XCode SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have created a qr code generator and i want to do time set in the qr code, so i used a date picker for time and it only shows hours and minutes. i want to use the date picker to show the result in qr code like this (12 34).
I have tried with the string but i don't know to do with the datetime

Code for string(Is working in XCode)

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import CoreImage.CIFilterBuiltins

struct Generate: View {
    @State var start = String
    let filter = CIFilter.qrCodeGenerator()
    let cont = CIContext()
    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: imageGenerate(start))
            .interpolation(.none)
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 150, height: 150, alignment: .center)
    }
    func imageGenerate(_ start: Int?)-> UIImage {
        let data = Data(start)
        filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
        if let qr = filter.outputImage {
            if let qrImage = cont.createCGImage(qr, from: qr.extent){
                return UIImage(cgImage: qrImage)
            }
        }
        return UIImage(systemName: "xmark") ?? UIImage()
    }
}
```

Code for datetime(not working)

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import CoreImage.CIFilterBuiltins

struct Generate: View {
    @State var start = Timer()
    let filter = CIFilter.qrCodeGenerator()
    let cont = CIContext()
    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: imageGenerate(start))
            .interpolation(.none)
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 150, height: 150, alignment: .center)
    }
    func imageGenerate(_ start: Timer)-> UIImage {
        let data = Data(start.[not utf8, don't know what should it be?])
        filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
        if let qr = filter.outputImage {
            if let qrImage = cont.createCGImage(qr, from: qr.extent){
                return UIImage(cgImage: qrImage)
            }
        }
        return UIImage(systemName: "xmark") ?? UIImage()
    }
}
```

Update Part
code for date picker

```
@State private var startTime = Date()
var body: some View {
        Form{
            Section {
                VStack{
                    Text("Please Select Start Time")
                        .padding(.bottom, 10)
                        .font(.system(size:20))
                        .bold()
                    DatePicker("", selection: $startTime, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                        .labelsHidden()
                        .datePickerStyle(.wheel)
                }
                
                VStack{
                    Picker(selection: $sMinutes, label: Text("Please Select Minutes"))
                    {
                        ForEach(0 ..< minutes.count) {
                            index in Text(self.minutes[index]).tag(index)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Button("Complete"){
                self.showflag.toggle()
            }
            .font(.system(size:20))
            .bold()
            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        }
```

Comment: Your first `Generate` that is supposed to work, does not make sense. You have `@State var start = String`, what's that? Then `imageGenerate(...)` that takes an `Int`. `...i want to use the date picker`, where is the date picker you want to use?

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine so first code i used string for test and it works, after that i want to use a date picker to use `Date()` in **start**. when i go to `let data =  Data(start.?)`  what sould it be?

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I want to ask if i want to add one integer for picker, what should i change in the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example code to show a qr code using a date picker.

The code uses a `DatePicker` to select the hours and minutes.
Then a `DateFormatter` to convert those into a string for the qr code generator.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var start = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DatePicker("", selection: $start, displayedComponents: [.hourAndMinute])
                .datePickerStyle(.wheel)
            Generate(start: $start)
        }
    }
}


struct Generate: View {
    @Binding var start: Date // <-- here
    
    let filter = CIFilter.qrCodeGenerator()
    let cont = CIContext()
    
    var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {  // <-- here
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        return df
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: imageGenerate(start))
            .interpolation(.none)
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 150, height: 150, alignment: .center)
    }
    
    func imageGenerate(_ start: Date)-> UIImage {
        let str = dateFormatter.string(from: start) // <-- here
        let data = str.data(using: .utf8) // <-- here
        filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
        if let qr = filter.outputImage {
            if let qrImage = cont.createCGImage(qr, from: qr.extent){
                return UIImage(cgImage: qrImage)
            }
        }
        return UIImage(systemName: "xmark") ?? UIImage()
    }
}
```

EDIT-1:

to put the qr code generation into a function, try this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var start = Date()
    @State var img: UIImage = UIImage()  // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DatePicker("", selection: $start, displayedComponents: [.hourAndMinute])
                .datePickerStyle(.wheel)
            
            Button("Show QR code", action: {
                img = imageGenerate(start)   // <-- here
            })
            
            Image(uiImage: img)
                .interpolation(.none)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 150, height: 150, alignment: .center)
        }
    }
    
    func imageGenerate(_ start: Date) -> UIImage {
        let filter = CIFilter.qrCodeGenerator()
        let cont = CIContext()
        
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter() // <-- here
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm" // <-- here

        let str = dateFormatter.string(from: start) // <-- here
        let data = str.data(using: .utf8) // <-- here
        filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
        if let qr = filter.outputImage {
            if let qrImage = cont.createCGImage(qr, from: qr.extent){
                return UIImage(cgImage: qrImage)
            }
        }
        return UIImage(systemName: "xmark") ?? UIImage()
    }
    
}
```

Comment: i want to ask how to put the function into a button?

Comment: updated my answer with a possible solution to put the qr code image generation function into a Button.

Comment: I have another question which is about qr code generator with multiple info, i have used your example to demo, do you know how to solve it?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "multiple info", what does that mean? Explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: sorry i mean multiple parameter in function for qr code generator

Comment: have a look at this link, https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html  it shows your how to pass multiple parameters to a Swift function, and it includes a number of examples, that you can use and study.